# Ubuntu dual boot: Windows boots in recovery mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, recovery-mode

I have a HP Elitebook Bang&Olufsen laptop installed with a corporate Windows OS distribution.
I recently decided to make it into a dual boot with Ubuntu 22.xx LTS. Steps:

1. Go into the only Windows partition with Admin privileges.
2. Disk Manager >> Free up disk space -- gives unused / unassigned disk space following the Windows Partition.
3. Rebooted, went into BIOS and changed boot order to boot from USB as first priority.
4. Inserted Ubuntu bootable USB disk and installed Ubuntu in unused partition with SWAP partition also.
5. Reset BIOS to primarily boot from Ubuntu bootloader (new entry)
6. Reboot computer
7. At GRUB loader window two options: Ubuntu or Windows
8. If I go into Ubuntu -- all works as it should
9. If I go into Windows -- reaches a factory reset / recovery mode and asks for a password - I cancel loading.
10. Instead of Step 5 I can go to BIOS and set primarily boot from Windows bootloader
11. Reboot computer
12. Directly boots into Windows partition with no problems

I am working with this BIOS changing hack each time I want to switch between Ubuntu and Windows. What is happening and how do I fix it please?

[I have not included any OS version numbers or screenshots because I do not know what is relevant and what is not. With my little knowledge I also have a hunch this is OS version agnostic and some mess up with partitioning or installing GRUB.I will provide them as and when helping people asked.]

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI mode? Vendors may call it BIOS, but it really has been UEFI since 2012. My Dell is UEFI only and Dell still calls it BIOS. Grub only boots working Windows. But that also means it cannot be hibernated & fast startup sets hibernation flag. Windows may turn fast start up back on with updates. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation